# Are these two expressions equal to each other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

Im working on a proof, and currently I'm trying to check some expressions to see if they are equal to each other. Using specific values as a test case, I get this expression

[image]

But I can't tell if they are equal to each other.

If I try simplifying them myself, I get $log_2{(12)} = 2log_2{(37)}-7$ and I still don't know if they are equal to each other. The difference of this is about $0.166056$ according to a math software. I think it's because of rounding errors, but I want to be sure.

Does anyone know if there is a way to check?

Thanks

Comment: Assume by contradiction that the two numbers are equal, write $13=12+1$ and eliminate fractions. You arrive at the contradiction $12=2^{\ldots}$.

Comment: Can you write out the steps?

Comment: Write $a=2^{7+2\log_2\ldots}$. Then we are asserting by contradiction that $$\frac{12}{a}=\frac{12+1}{1+a}.$$That is, $$12+12a = 12a +a.$$ And so we obtain the contradiction $12=a$: this is clearly impossible since $a$ is a very big number.

Comment: But if I try to calculate $a$ in the math software, I get $13.4638$.....

Comment: I was doing the same and I obtain the same result as you: at first glance I thought it was a bigger number. Still, I think it is enough to conclude that $a\ne 12$.

Comment: I'm not sure, but If I simplify the $a=12$, I get $log_2{(12)} = 2log_2{(37)}-7$, and the difference is $0.166056$ with floating point errors...

Comment: Try writing, by contradiction, $12=a$. That is $$12=2^7 \frac{12^2}{37^2}.$$ Simplify $12$ and you are left with $1=2^7\frac{12}{37^2}$. This is clearly a contradiction since the denominator has no factor of $2$.

Comment: Even in floating point, you should expect at least six significant figures, not two (barring catastrophic cancellation, which isn't happening here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{12}{x}=\frac{13}{1+x}$$
from here we have $x=12$ then $$2^y=12$$ and we have $y=\log_2 12$ assume

$$7+2(\log_2 12 - \log_237)=\log_2 12$$

is true then you have $$\log_2 128=7 = \log_2 37^2-\log_2 (12)=\log_2 37^2/12$$

since $37^2/12\neq 128$, your assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**  $\ 12 = 2^{\large 7+2\log_2(a)} = 2^7 a^2\,\Rightarrow\, a^2 = 6/2^6\,\Rightarrow\,a = \sqrt{6}/8,\,$ contra $\,a = 12/37\in\Bbb Q$